# dropdown menu with checkbox error in flutter

Tags: flutter

i have following code to put a bunch of checkboxes inside a dropDownMenu
this code worked fine before null safety but now it shows some error

```
ActivityType dropdownValue = ActivityType(activityTypeName: "hell", id: 1);

List<ActivityType> activityList = [
ActivityType(activityTypeName: "hell", id: 1),
ActivityType(activityTypeName: "para", id: 2)
];
List<ActivityType> selectedCheckBoxItems1 = [];

DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (dynamic val) {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            iconSize: 24,
            items: activityList
                .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: StatefulBuilder(
                        builder:
                            (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                          return CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(e.activityTypeName ?? ""),
                              value: selectedCheckBoxItems1.indexWhere(
                                          (element) =>
                                              element.activityTypeName ==
                                              e.activityTypeName) >=
                                      0
                                  ? true
                                  : false,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setSelectedCheckBox1(e, value!);
                                setState(() {});
                              });
                        },
                      ),
                    )))
                .toList(),
          ))
```

> > The following assertion was thrown building testDrop(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _testDropState#146a8): There should
> > be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of
> > 'ActivityType'.  Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were
> > detected with the same value
> > 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line
> > 850 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
> > items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) {
> > return item.value == value;
> > }).length == 1'